# need to disable previous dates from current date in datetime picker

Tags: jquery, html, datetime

I am using datetime picker,but it is displaying all the dates.I need to show dates from current date and need to disable all the previous dates from current date.Following is my HTML and jquery code

```js
jQuery(function() {
  $('.abc').datetimepicker({
    minDate: 0
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label class="control-label">Date and Time</label>
  <span class="star">*</span>
  <div class="input-group date form_datetime abc">
    <input type="text" size="16" readonly class="form-control" name="date_of_event" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn default date-reset" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </button>
   <button class="btn default date-set" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.abc').datetimepicker({ minDate: new Date(); });`

Comment: @Rupali if your using jquery ui datetime picker then you should use datepicker not datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
`new Date()` Will give you today's date.

When you assign that `new Date()` to the `minDate`, datepicker will disable all previous dates for you.

```
jQuery(function () {
        $('.abc').datepicker({ minDate: new Date(); });

    });
```

Comment: @Rupali Check this

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.abc').datetimepicker({ minDate: new Date(), });

});
```

Comment: jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.abc').datetimepicker({ minDate: new Date() });
});

Comment: try minDate : 0

Comment: @Arun-Nothing is working...tried all.My minDate is not working

Answer (score 0):

Hey just do little change in jquery function as follows :

```
    jQuery(function () {
       $('.abc').datetimepicker({ minDate: dateToday  });   
    });
```

Comment: DateTime dateToday = new DateTime()

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-4"> 
   <label class="control-label">Date and Time</label>
   <span class="star">*</span>
    <div class="input-group date form_datetime ">
    <input type="text" size="16" readonly class="form-control abc" name="date_of_event" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn default date-reset" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="btn default date-set" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
   </button>
   </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

What is wrong in this code is the position where you have defined "abc" class. Try the code above it will work. Class "abc" will be placed on input tag as shown in the example.

Comment: @Rupali check this solution .